# Submit a form on click but not submit using jquery and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

i want to submit all form's infomation with an onclick event function (i don't want to use a conventional submit ). How can i use the post or ajax method?

here is my code

```
$("#login_form").bind("click", function() {
    var qtyVal = document.getElementsByName('id[]').length; 

    $.ajax({
        type        : "post",
        cache   :   false,
        url     : "abcd.php?ref=xyz",
        data        : $(this).serializeArray(),
        success: function(data) {
        $.fancybox(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: What element exactly should be clicked?

Comment: what doesn't work then? you should edit your question and be more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use from `this` keyword here. You click on a button to send the form data,so `this` will return you the button element. You should not use from 'click' event for your form too. You can do like the following code:

```
function send(){

$.ajax({
    type        : "post",
    cache   :   false,
    url     : "abcd.php?ref=xyz",
    data    : $('#frm').serializeArray(),
    success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
    }
});
return false;} 



<form id="frm"><input type="button" id="submit" onclick="send()" /></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) ?

If `login_form` is *really* a form (i.e. `<form id="login_form">`), you can do:

```
$("#login_form").submit();
```

to submit your form the conventional way without AJAX call.

Comment: no, i want to submit a form using onclick() with ajax and jquery, without using form submit()